# how to pass search value from one component to another

Tags: reactjs, firebase

hello veryone im trying to make a simple search bar to search my firebase database based on the search bar queires. im trying to get the input value from 1 component and then in component 2 display the results based on the input value from component 1 using firebase queries. Can someone tell me what im doing wrong ? thanks

1 component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { updateFilter } from '../../actions/filtered';
import { CarsRef, timeRef } from '../admin/reference';
import Searchresults from './searchresult';


class TopSearchBar extends Component {
  state = {
    make: '',
    body: '',
    priceRange: ''
  }
  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.updateFilter(this.state);

    this.props.history.push('/cars2')

  }





  render(){
    let content = null;

     if (content !==null ) {
        <Searchresults make={this.state.make} />
}


else {

  <p> h </p>

}

    let searchMake = ["Audi","Honda","Lamborghini","Maserati", "Subaru","Toyota"];

    let cars = {
      Audi: [ {body: "Sedan"}, {body: "Coupe"}, {body: "SUV"} ],
      Honda: [ {body: "Sedan"}, {body: "Van"}, {body: "SUV"} ],
      Lamborghini: [ {body: "Coupe"} ],
      Maserati: [ {body: "Coupe"}, {body: "SUV"} ],
      Mercedes: [ {body: "Convertible"}, {body: "Coupe"} ],
      Subaru: [ {body: "Hatchback"} ],
      Toyota: [ {body: "SUV"}, {body: "Sedan"}, {body: "Truck"} ]
    }

    let makes = searchMake.map((make, i) => {
      return (
        <option key={i} value={make}>
          {make}
        </option>
      )
    })

    if(this.state.make) {
      var body = cars[this.state.make].map((make, i) => {
        return (
          <option key={i} value={make.body}>
              {make.body}
          </option>)
      })
    }

    return(

      <div className="top-search-bar">
        <div className="container text-align">
          <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <div className="row">
              <div className="col-3">
                <select className="form-control"
                    value={this.state.make}
                    onChange={(e)=>this.setState({make: e.target.value})}
                  >
                  <option value="" disabled selected>Make</option>
                    {makes}
                </select>
              </div>
              <div className="col-3">
                <select className="form-control"
                  value={this.state.body}
                  onChange={(e)=>this.setState({body: e.target.value})}
                  >
                    <option value="" disabled selected>Body Type</option>
                    { makes ? body : null }
                  </select>
              </div>
              <div className="col-3">
                <select className="form-control"
                  value={this.state.priceRange}
                  onChange={(e)=>this.setState({priceRange: e.target.value})}
                  >
                    <option value="" disabled selected>Price</option>
                    <option value="lowHigh">Low To High</option>
                    <option value="highLow">High To Low</option>
                  </select>
              </div>
              <div className="col-3">
                  <button type="submit" className="btn btn-success btn-block" onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Search</button>
              </div>
            </div>
            {content}
          </form>

        </div>
      </div>

    );
  }
}
```

2nd component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Car from './car';
import { CarsRef, timeRef } from '../admin/reference';

import { CardImg, Button, Row, Col, Table } from 'reactstrap';
import { getsinglecar } from '../../actions/cars';
import Icon from 'react-icons-kit';
import { bin } from 'react-icons-kit/icomoon';
import { getCarsThunk } from '../../actions/cars';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';



    class Searchresults extends Component {
      // ...



      state = {
        Cars: [],
       Carsloading: true
      };
      handleDelete = (id) => {
        this.props.deleteCar(id);
      }




     componentWillMount() { 


    alert(`${this.props.make}`); // returns undefined 

     CarsRef.orderByChild(`${this.props.make}`).startAt(`${this.props.make}`).endAt(`${this.props.make}`).on('value', (snap) => {

     let Cars = []
        snap.forEach((child) => {
       Cars.push({ ...child.val(), key: child.key });
        });

          console.log(Cars);
          this.setState({ Cars: Cars, CarsLoading: false });
        });

    }
      render() {
        const { Cars, CarsLoading } = this.state;
        const orderedcars = Cars;

        let carList;


        if (CarsLoading) {
          carList = <div className="TaskList-empty">Loading...</div>;
        } else {

          carList = (
            <ul className="TaskList">
              {Cars.map(car => (
                <div>
                  <Row>
                    <Col md="12">
                      <div className="card border-secondary mb-3">
                        <div className="card-header text-success">
                          <h4>
                            <Link to={`/cars/${car.id}`}>

                            </Link>
                          </h4>
                        </div>
                        <div className="card-body">
                          <Row>
                            <Col md="5">
                              <CardImg
                                className="carlist-margin"
                                top
                                width="100%"
                                src={car.link}
                                alt={car.make}
                              />
                            </Col>
                            <Col md="4">
                              <Table className="striped">
                                <tbody>
                                  <tr>
                                    <td>Engine:</td>
                                    <td>{car.engine}</td>
                                  </tr>
                                  <tr>
                                    <td>Drive Type:</td>
                                    <td>{car.drive_type}</td>
                                  </tr>
                                  <tr>
                                    <td>Body:</td>
                                    <td>{car.body_type}</td>
                                  </tr>
                                  <tr>
                                    <td>Exterior Color:</td>
                                    <td>{car.ext_color}</td>
                                  </tr>
                                  <tr>
                                    <td>Interior Color:</td>
                                    <td>{car.int_color}</td>
                                  </tr>
                                  <tr>
                                    <td>Transmission:</td>
                                    <td>{car.transmission}</td>
                                  </tr>
                                  <tr>
                                    <td>VIN:</td>
                                    <td>{car.vin}</td>
                                  </tr>
                                </tbody>
                              </Table>
                            </Col>
                            <Col md="3">
                              <Table className="striped">
                                <tbody>
                                  <tr>
                                    <td className="text-primary text-right">
                                      <strong>MSRP:</strong>
                                    </td>
                                    <td className="text-primary text-right">
                                      <strong>${car.price}</strong>
                                    </td>
                                  </tr>
                                  <tr>
                                    <td className="text-danger text-right">
                                      Dealer Discount:
                                    </td>
                                    <td className="text-danger text-right">
                                      {car.sale}%
                                    </td>
                                  </tr>
                                  <tr>
                                    <td className="text-primary text-right">
                                      <strong>Total:</strong>
                                    </td>
                                    <td className="text-primary text-right">
                                      <strong>
                                        ${car.price - (car.price * car.sale) / 100}
                                      </strong>
                                    </td>
                                  </tr>
                                  <tr>
                                    <td className="text-primary text-right">
                                      Est. Lease:
                                    </td>
                                    <td className="text-primary text-right">
                                      $230/m*
                                    </td>
                                  </tr>
                                  <tr>
                                    <td className="text-primary text-right">
                                      Est. Finance:
                                    </td>
                                    <td className="text-primary text-right">
                                      $330/m*
                                    </td>
                                  </tr>
                                  <tr>
                                    <td className="text-right" />
                                    <td className="text-right">
                                      <Link to={`/cars/${car.id}`}>
                                        <Button className="btn btn-success">
                                          More
                                        </Button>
                                      </Link>
                                    </td>
                                  </tr>
                                </tbody>
                              </Table>
                            </Col>
                          </Row>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </Col>
                  </Row>
                </div>
              ))}
            </ul>
          );
        }

        return carList;
      }
    }


    export default Searchresults

;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to connect your 2nd component to the Redux Store and create a `MapStateToProps` to have access to the properties you need.

First create the `MapStateToProps`

```
 const mapStateToProps = state => {
   return {
      make: state.make// place here the name of the property in your reducer
   }
 }
```

Then connect it to the Redux Store.

```
 export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Searchresults)
```

From now on you will have access the prop "make" (or whatever name you give in on your `MapStateToProps`).

Take a look at this example from [Redux Documentation](https://redux.js.org/basics/usage-with-react#containers-visibletodolist-js)

If you show me your actions, I may be more specific in my response.

Comment: so you think redux is best to acomplish this? i cant use props?

Comment: I assumed you were using redux because `updateFilter` is an action and you import some redux-related methods. You can surely use it as props, you just need to pass it to the component. I did not see where you call <Searchresults/> to see what can be done. Without redux you would have to call with the prop, <Searchresults make=[data]/>.

Comment: <Searchresults make={this.state.make} /> is giving me undefined

Comment: `this.state.make` may be undefined at the moment you call it. I would have to see how and when your call <Searchresults/> to see why at that moment `this.state.make` is undefined. The code you show here doesn't include how you handle the info you get from the forms, how you process it, where you store it, how you save it (by the amount of redux boilerplate I assumed you used redux). Show me more so that I can try to help.

Comment: ive edited the code

Comment: take a look if you can thanks

Comment: I saw you added `<Searchresults make={this.state.make} />` just after your `render ()` method starts inside an If Statement. This will not work because you are not _returning_ the  `<Searchresults make={this.state.make} />`. Only JSX components inside a `return` statement are _renderered_. Your first if statement is not rendering or executing the  `<Searchresults make={this.state.make} />`.

Comment: ok i got it to work now it was a routing issue